# Pull URL String from Array and place in IBAction

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to randomize the arrayList and then pull the URL to an IBAction that would then open the page.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let ArrayList = [
        ["A", "A2", "http://a.com"],
        ["B", "B2", "http://b.com"],
        ["C", "C2", "http://c.com"],
    ]

    let pickArrayList = ArrayList[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(ArrayList.count)))]
    label1.text = pickArrayList[0]
    label2.text = pickArrayList[1]
}
```

Below is the IBAction but I receive an error saying that pickArrayList[2] is an unresolved Identifier.

```swift
@IBAction func didTapButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(pickArrayList[2])!)  
    }
```

Thanks in advance,
Swift Noobie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `pickArrayList` is declared as local variable in the scope of `viewDidLoad`.

Declare `pickArrayList` as a property on the top level of the class

```
var pickArrayList : [String]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let arrayList = [
        ["A", "A2", "http://a.com"],
        ["B", "B2", "http://b.com"],
        ["C", "C2", "http://c.com"],
    ]

    pickArrayList = arrayList[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayList.count)))]
    label1.text = pickArrayList[0]
    label2.text = pickArrayList[1]
}
```

Please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with lowercase letter.

Comment: Man this is so close. I get a "fatal error" because it says there is a bad execution within the @IBAction. "UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: pickArrayList[2])!)" If I remove the "string:" then I get an error that "Argument Labels (_:) do not match any available overloads."

Comment: `URL(string: ..` is mandatory. Make sure that string in `pickArrayList[2]` is a valid URL format or use optional binding.

Comment: Okay, so I have tried a bunch of different URLs and none have worked thus far. When I change the string value to "*https://google.com*" as opposed to pickArrayList[2], it has no problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Once again, the string must be convertible to URL. Check the url in a browser or a playground. `URL(string:` returns `nil` if the URL format is not valid. But this is beyond the issue of the question.